# Convert lines with sublines into single lines

Tags: mysql, linux, awk, sed

I have a massive text file that I need to import to an SQL database.
The problem is that the file contain a several lines per record, so I need everything in single lines per record.

The textfile looks like this now;

```
L;1;100;Product1;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;
T;TEXT2;177
T;TEXT;130
T;TEXT;156x55
O;2;40448652267;43242;
O;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product2;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;
T;TEXT2;177
T;TEXT;130
T;TEXT;156x55
O;2;40448652267;43242;
O;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product2;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;
T;TEXT2;177
T;TEXT;130
T;TEXT;156x55
O;2;40448652267;43242;
O;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product3;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;
T;TEXT2;177
T;TEXT;130
T;TEXT;156x55
O;2;40448652267;43242;
O;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product4;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;
T;TEXT2;177
T;TEXT;130
T;TEXT;156x55
O;2;40448652267;43242;
O;3;0481439;344;
```

And I need it to end up like this so it will be easy to import it to the SQL database;

Is it any SED command to use for this convertation, or is it a better way to do it?

```
L;1;100;Product1;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;TEXT2;177;TEXT;130;TEXT;156x55;2;40448652267;43242;;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product2;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;TEXT2;177;TEXT;130;TEXT;156x55;2;40448652267;43242;;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product3;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;TEXT2;177;TEXT;130;TEXT;156x55;2;40448652267;43242;;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product4;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;TEXT2;177;TEXT;130;TEXT;156x55;2;40448652267;43242;;3;0481439;344;
```

All tips on howto get this data into a mySQL database in the best way is appreciated :)

Comment: probably possible with sed, but better suited for awk...

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, thanks for using code tags. kindly check my awk code once and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: apart from adding what you tried, you should also add details of conversion - like deleting the first field from non `L;` lines

Comment: according to your output - you should have mentioned if there are additional requirements: whether `T;` and `O;` should really be removed. Update your question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` one-liner:

```
awk '{printf("%s", /^L/ ? (p?RS:"") $0:substr($0, index($0,";")+1 ));p=1}END{print ""}' infile
```

OR ( lengthy )

```
awk '/^L/{ if(p)print ""; printf("%s",$0);next}{ printf("%s",substr($0,index($0,";")+1));p=1}END{print ""}' infile
```

Better Readable:

```
awk '/^L/{ 
           if(p)print ""; 
           printf("%s",$0);
           next
         }
         { 
           printf("%s",substr($0,index($0,";")+1));
           p=1
         }
      END{
           print ""
         }
    ' infile
```

Input:

```
$ cat infile
L;1;100;Product1;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;
T;TEXT2;177
T;TEXT;130
T;TEXT;156x55
O;2;40448652267;43242;
O;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product2;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;
T;TEXT2;177
T;TEXT;130
T;TEXT;156x55
O;2;40448652267;43242;
O;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product2;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;
T;TEXT2;177
T;TEXT;130
T;TEXT;156x55
O;2;40448652267;43242;
O;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product3;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;
T;TEXT2;177
T;TEXT;130
T;TEXT;156x55
O;2;40448652267;43242;
O;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product4;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;
T;TEXT2;177
T;TEXT;130
T;TEXT;156x55
O;2;40448652267;43242;
O;3;0481439;344;
```

Output:

```
$ awk '{printf("%s", /^L/ ? (p?RS:"") $0:substr($0, index($0,";")+1 ));p=1}END{print ""}' infile
L;1;100;Product1;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;TEXT2;177TEXT;130TEXT;156x552;40448652267;43242;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product2;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;TEXT2;177TEXT;130TEXT;156x552;40448652267;43242;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product2;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;TEXT2;177TEXT;130TEXT;156x552;40448652267;43242;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product3;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;TEXT2;177TEXT;130TEXT;156x552;40448652267;43242;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product4;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;TEXT2;177TEXT;130TEXT;156x552;40448652267;43242;3;0481439;344;
```

Comment: Thanks! This do almost as I need, in the original file I have both [CR] and [LF] linebreak after evey line. When I run the sctipt I still have [CR] line break. Anyway I can remove this too?

Comment: @Andreas will you please add other sample too ?

Comment: I uploaded an screenshot of the example here, as it difficult to show caracters in this post :)  https://www.dropbox.com/s/g72kg00ouz0fxa5/line.png

Comment: One more question.. After TEXT2;177 it is missing a ; any idea how I can get that?

Answer (score 0):

awk to save:

```
awk '{printf("%s%s",NR==1 && $0 ~ /^L;/?"":($0 ~ /^L;/?RS:""),$0)} END{print ""}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
L;1;100;Product1;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;T;TEXT2;177T;TEXT;130T;TEXT;156x55O;2;40448652267;43242;O;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product2;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;T;TEXT2;177T;TEXT;130T;TEXT;156x55O;2;40448652267;43242;O;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product2;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;T;TEXT2;177T;TEXT;130T;TEXT;156x55O;2;40448652267;43242;O;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product3;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;T;TEXT2;177T;TEXT;130T;TEXT;156x55O;2;40448652267;43242;O;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product4;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;T;TEXT2;177T;TEXT;130T;TEXT;156x55O;2;40448652267;43242;O;3;0481439;344;
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation and non-one liner form of solution too.

```
awk '{
printf("%s%s",NR==1 && $0 ~ /^L;/?"":($0 ~ /^L;/?RS:""),$0) ##Using printf here to print the lines. %s%s to print the lines, So while printing them mentioning 2 conditions here NR==1(where it checks if line is very first line of Input_file and line starts from L; then print NULL else if a line starts from L; then print RS(whose default value is new line) else print NULL value. For second string simple print current line.
}                                                           ##So idea behind this logic is simple to print a new line which starts from L; apart from first line, so that we could get output as per OP.
END{
print ""                                                    ##In the END block to print a new line simple printing NULL so that a new line will be inserted.
}
' Input_file                                                ##Mentioning the Input_file here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `sed` solution,

```
sed ':a;/O;3/!{N;s/\n//;ba}' file
```

Brief explanation,

- Target to remove all '\n' except the line starts with "O;3".
- `:a`: set the label 'a' at the beginning of the script
- `/O;3/!{N;s/\n//;ba}`: if lines don't start with "O;3", append the next line and remove the '\n' as well. Then we go back to label 'a' to process following lines.

Answer (score 0):

**Awk** solution:

```
awk -v ORS= 'NR>1 && /^L/{print "\n"}/^T/{sub(/.;/,";")}END{ print "\n" }1' file
```

The output:

```
L;1;100;Product1;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;;TEXT2;177;TEXT;130;TEXT;156x55O;2;40448652267;43242;O;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product2;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;;TEXT2;177;TEXT;130;TEXT;156x55O;2;40448652267;43242;O;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product2;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;;TEXT2;177;TEXT;130;TEXT;156x55O;2;40448652267;43242;O;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product3;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;;TEXT2;177;TEXT;130;TEXT;156x55O;2;40448652267;43242;O;3;0481439;344;
L;1;100;Product4;Text;2;Text2;;20171006;;;1;;76;;;U;1000;;;TEXT2;177;TEXT;130;TEXT;156x55O;2;40448652267;43242;O;3;0481439;344;
```

Comment: You probably misread, need some more changes `1000;;T;`, T shouldn't come

Comment: @AkshayHegde, the OP did not mention deleting of `T;`. If you guarantee that it's requied - see my update

Comment: @AkshayHegde, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46599602/convert-lines-with-sublines-into-single-lines/46601591#comment80155681_46599602

Comment: Yeah true, as per expected o/p it looks like so

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one too

```
while read l;do [ "${l%%;*}" = 'L' ]&&{ [ $n ] &&echo "${n%;}";n="$l";}||n="$n${l#*;};";done<infile;echo "${n%;}"
```